# add contents of a cell to text file if checkbox is checked using excel 2010 vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the below ***Excel 2010*** VBA that is in two parts. The first portion checks if a CheckBox on a sheet is checked, if it then it adds the value of a specified cell to the ***sample_descriptor.txt*** in the portion below that. Currently I am getting a

> subscript out of range error

and am not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this task.  Thank you :).  The value for comment1 is `F9`, comment2 is `F10`, comment3 is `F11`, and comment4 is `F12`

**VBA**

```
' ADD COMMENT IF ANY '
If CheckBox17.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F9") = ActiveSheet.Range("F9").Value
Else
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F9") = "No Issues"
End If

If CheckBox17.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F10") = ActiveSheet.Range("10").Value
Else
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F10") = "No Issues"
End If

If CheckBox17.Value = True Then
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F11") = ActiveSheet.Range("F11").Value
Else
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F11") = "No Issues"
End If

If CheckBox17.Value = True Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F12") = ActiveSheet.Range("F12").Value
Else
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F12") = "No Issues"
End If

Unload Me

'WRITE TO SAMPLE DESCRIPTOR.txt '
    Open MyDirectory & "sample_descriptor.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Experiment Sample" & vbTab & "Control Sample" & vbTab & "Display Name" & vbTab & "Gender" & vbTab & "Control Gender" & vbTab & "Spikein" & vbTab & "Location" & vbTab & "Barcode" & vbTab & "Medical Record" & vbTab & "Date of Birth" & vbTab & "Order Date"
    Print #1, "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_532Block1.txt" & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_635Block1.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & vbTab & Split(ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Value, " [")(0) & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B12").Value & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C200").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D200").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E200").Value & IIf(Sheet.CheckBox17, vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("F9").Value, "")
    Print #1, "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_532Block2.txt" & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_635Block2.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value & vbTab & Split(ActiveSheet.Range("C11").Value, " [")(0) & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C12").Value & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C201").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D201").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E201").Value & IIf(Sheet.CheckBox17, vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("F10").Value, "")
    Print #1, "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_532Block3.txt" & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_635Block3.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("D9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Value & vbTab & Split(ActiveSheet.Range("D11").Value, " [")(0) & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D12").Value & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C202").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D202").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E202").Value & IIf(Sheet1.CheckBox17, vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("F11").Value, "")
    Print #1, "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_532Block4.txt" & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & "_635Block4.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value & vbTab & Split(ActiveSheet.Range("E11").Value, " [")(0) & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E12").Value & vbTab & "2571683" & MyBarCode & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C203").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D203").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E203").Value & IIf(Sheet1.CheckBox17, vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("F12").Value, "")
    Close #1
```

**file format**

```
x               
x   1   2   3   4   
x   11  22  33  44  
x   --- --- --- --- 
x   Male    Male    Female  Male    
x   --- --- --- --- 
x   1   2   3   4                       Please check the box to add comment
x   1111    2222    3333    4444        (checkbox17)
x   xxx,xxx xxx,xxx xxx,xxx xxx,xxx     comment1
x   Male    Male    Female  Male        comment2
x   xx  xx  xx  xx                      comment3
x   x   x   x   x                       comment4
```

Comment: why do you have the same `If CheckBox17.Value = True Then` 4 times ? why not just 1 and put all of your actions below ? is it suppose to be `CheckBox17` for each sheet ?

Comment: There is only 1 checkbox17 one the sheet, I will post an example in an edit.  Thank you :).

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: what's that `Unload Me` for? Are you dealing with a worksheet `Checkbox` or a `Userform` one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("10").Value
```

into:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F10").Value
```

But you can shorten down your code to:

```
If CheckBox17 Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F9:F12").value = ActiveSheet.Range("F9:F12").value
Else
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F9:F12") = "No Issues"
End If
```

Comment: Did you notice the errors in his last 4 code lines (before `Close #1`) ? he has `IIf(Sheet.CheckBox17` and `IIf(Sheet1.CheckBox17`

Comment: Should no ActiveX checkbox control named `CheckBox17` be in `Sheet1`, it wouldn't even compile! So it's not the cause of the _"subscript out of range"_ error the OP's complaining for.

Comment: I shortened the code as you suggested but am getting a `subscript out of range error` on the line `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F9:F12").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("F9:F12").Value`.  Thank you :).

Comment: looks like your currently _active_ workbook hasn't any worksheet named after "Sheet1": check in the Immediate Window if your currently _active_ workbook is the one you're expecting (`?ActiveWorkbook.Name`) and if it has any "Sheet1" worksheet (`?ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name`)